# How can I replace all value fields in an XML file having particular key value using sed or any other Unix tool?

Tags: xml, linux, unix, sed

How can I replace all value fields in an XML file having perticular key value using sed or any other command from Unix?

Example, I have `file.xml` with me and I want to change the value to `256m` which has `key= "-Xmx"`

```
<entry key="-Xmx" value="512m" />
```

Example:

```
<entry key="-Xmx" value="512m" />
```

I want to replace value as `256m` for any entry having key as `-Xmx`.

Comment: It's not recommended,  because pretty fundamentally XML is NOT regex friendly. Sometimes it'll work, but it's not reliable.  Is perl an option? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below,

```
$ echo '<entry key="-Xmx" value="512m" />' | sed 's/\b\(key="-Xmx" *value="\)[^"]*m"/\1256m"/g'
<entry key="-Xmx" value="256m" />
```

Comment: How would I know that this replacement is taking place in my file sample.xml only? As I can not see any input paramater here. Thanks.

Comment: add `i` parameter to save the changes made. like `sed -i  's/\b\(key="-Xmx" *value="\)[^"]*m"/\1256m"/g' file.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Editing XML with sed is not a good idea, since sed works on lines and XML is not a line-based format. You will end up with solutions that break as soon as attributes are specified in a different order, with other attributes between them or on different lines -- all of which is allowed in XML but difficult to handle for sed.

Instead, use a proper XML-handling tool like `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//entry[@key="-Xmx"]/@value' -v 256m filename.xml
```

where `//entry[@key="-Xmx"]/@value` is an XPath expression selecting the `value` attribute of all `entry` nodes whose `key` attribute is `-Xmx`, and `xmlstarlet ed -u xpath -v value` sets the value of the selected XPath.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not quite what you asked for, but I'll stand by my assertion that using regex for parsing XML is a bad idea.

See: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

[Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

So I'd be thinking perlishly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $xml = '<XML>
  <entry key="-Xmx" value="512m" />
</XML>';

sub amend_entry {
    my ( $twig, $entry ) = @_;
    if ( $entry->att('key') eq '-Xmx' ) {
        $entry->set_att( 'value' => "256m" );
    }
}

my $parser = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { entry => \&amend_entry } )
    ->parse($xml)->print;
```

(And yes, it's not a one liner. But this is more aimed at being illustrative of the technique, rather than trying to save keystrokes).